# Android tiled background one row

Tags: android

I want to have a tiled background with an image repeating horizontally but not vertically in an Android app. In other words, I want a tiled row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In this code, replace **yourXYZ** with your objetcs

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) yourView.findViewById(R.id.yourContainer);
BitmapDrawable bmp = (BitmapDrawable) yourContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourBackground);

bmp.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{
    rl.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
}
else
{
    rl.setBackground(bg);
}
```